# How to give alias to CASE WHEN THEN SELECT statement

Tags: mysqli, case

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT id,memberID AS member,
    CASE 
    WHEN svDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN svDate
    WHEN repeatStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN repeatStartDate
    WHEN vvStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN vvStartDate
    END
FROM services  
ORDER BY `CASE 
    WHEN svDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN svDate
    WHEN repeatStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN repeatStartDate
    WHEN vvStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN vvStartDate
    END` DESC
```

Can anyone tell me how to give this large case statement an alias of dateBeg so that I can use dateBeg in the field selection (SELECT id,member,dateBeg) and also in the ORDER BY clause (ORDER BY dateBeg)

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the `CASE` to dateBeg as follows;

```
SELECT id,memberID AS member,
CASE 
WHEN svDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN svDate
WHEN repeatStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN repeatStartDate
WHEN vvStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN vvStartDate
END AS dateBeg
FROM services
```

The `AS` keyword generally is not necessary so `END dateBag` should work as well.

When it comes to `ORDER BY`, you can now use the `dateBag` reference as it is set.

```
SELECT id,memberID AS member,
CASE 
WHEN svDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN svDate
WHEN repeatStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN repeatStartDate
WHEN vvStartDate<>"0000-00-00 00:00:00" THEN vvStartDate
END AS dateBeg
FROM services 
ORDER BY dateBeg DESC
```

Comment: I actually tried that and received errors.  The fact that you posted it might speak to my mysql version or something else...here are the errors:     2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 214)
Unexpected token. (near "dateBeg" at position 217)

Comment: Are you able to run SELECT version() in your terminal to see what version you’re running?

Comment: 10.0.36-MariaDB